# How to CAST twice an element in a row JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I've done a query with PostgreSQL that retrieves certain data as I expected: (It works)

```sql
SELECT distinct d.data 
FROM myScheme.myTable d, myScheme.mySecondTable g, json_array_elements(d.data->>'categorys') e 
where d.data->>'categorys' is not null 
AND e::text::int in (g.id_product_category_magento)
AND e::text::int IN (21718, 17);
```

The problem is when I try to do the same query with Java using JPA. This is not worked script:

```java
@Query(
    nativeQuery = true,
    value = "SELECT DISTINC d.data " +
        "FROM myScheme.myTable d, myScheme.mySecondTable g, " +
        "json_array_elements(d.data->>'categorys') e " +
        "where d.id = :id AND d.data->>'categorys' is not null " +
        "AND CAST(CAST(e as text) as Integer) in (g.id_product_category_magento) " +
        "AND CAST(CAST(e as text) as Integer) IN (:categories)"
)
List<ServiceDefinition> yest(Set<Long> categories, @Param("id") Long id);
```

The stack trace throws the following error message:

```
No dialect for Mapping JDBC 1111
```

Things to keep in mind:

- b.data ->> 'categorys' is an array of Strings that contains string values such as: ['123', '456', '789'] and should return each one of this values.

Pd: I'm not sure if this is the right way to cast a value twice: `AND CAST(CAST(e as text) as Integer)`.

Comment: In short I think you are over complicating this. 1) Why not use `json_array_elements_text()` that will return `text` and save a cast? 2) What is the value that `d.data->>'categorys'` is returning? Because `->>` returns `text`. Add information as update to question.

Comment: In one hand I already edited the post in order to fulfilled your suggestion.

In the other hand, yes, you are right, I saved a cast using `json_array_elements_text()`, but now it throws the following error message: `operator does not exist: integer = bytea`. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this:

1. I saved from casting each element twice by using `json_array_elements_text` instead of `json_array_elements`, the first one returns the values already as Strings. The second one was producing this error message: `No dialect for mapping 1111` due to a bad cast syntax made by me. This thanks to the wonderful suggestion from @AdrianKlaver
2. Doing `select d.data` seemed not to work, because it was returning an unknown data type for Hibernate, instead I returned `d.id`because I was really expecting each categoryId as Long type.
3. Used this `CAST(e as int4)` instead of this `as Integer`
4. Removed an extra @Param (id) of my **yest()** method

The final query is as shown below:

```
@Query(
        nativeQuery = true,
        value = "SELECT distinct d.id FROM myScheme.myTable d, myScheme.mySecondTable g " +
                ",json_array_elements_text(d.data->>'categorys') e " +
                "where d.data->>'categorys' is not null " +
                "AND CAST(e as int4) in (g.id_product_category_magento) " +
                "AND CAST(e as int4) in (:categories)"
)
List<Long> yest(List<Long> categories);
```

Hope this helps someone in the future. :)